# Is calling a function that returns a function with new different than just invoking it normally?

Tags: javascript

So let's say I have a javascript function

```
function A(){
    return function(){
        console.log('something');
        return new B();
    }
}
```

Is calling this using `new A();` any different than `A();`?

Comment: Related - [What is the 'new' keyword in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1646698/what-is-the-new-keyword-in-javascript) Dupe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that function has an explicit `return` and makes no use of `this`, there is no difference in the result of running it with or without `new`.

Comment: Agree - there would be no difference in the result.  But, one would think that using `new A()` would actually create a new object that would subsequently be garbage collected when something else was returned from the function so the `new A()` would probably perform worse.  A [jsPerf](http://jsperf.com/new-perf) confirms that `new A()` is 10%-80% slower depending upon browser.

Comment: "Since that function has an explicit `return` and makes no use of `this`". Could you tell us what you mean by "that function"? (`A()` or the anonymous function?). Also I think the result will be equivalent regardless of the use of `this` (See my answer for the explanation and please let me know if I'm missing something).

Answer (score 1):

When you call the function without "new", what is it that you suspect "this" is pointing to? It'll be "window." Updating that is slower than updating the freshly-built new object you'll be using when you invoke it with "new".

Comment: Well there actually is no 'this' in function A, sorry I forgot to add it too my post but the reason I'm wanting to use new is because the nested function calls new on another function, and I find it a little easier to understand that a functions return an object if a put new there

Answer (score 0):

Others have given answers about the result (is the use of `new` equivalent to not using it or not?), but let me explain *why* following two results are equivalent:

```
var no_new = A();
var with_new = new A();
```

The relevant part of the ECMAScript is [section 13.2.2](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-13.2.2) (I will omit and simplify some information and adapt the contents of that section to suit this answer). This is what happens when `new A()` is executed:

1. A new object is created.
2. The `prototype` of function `A` is examined:

   1. If the prototype of `A` is an object, newly created object's `prototype` is set to `A`'s prototype.
   2. If not, newly created object's `prototype` is set to the default prototype of `Object`.
3. Function `A()` is called, and the result is examined.

   1. If the result is an object, the result will be the return value of `new`.
   2. Else the newly created object will be the return value of `new`.

In your case, the execution will take the path 3.1, aka `new` operator will return a reference to the inner anonymous function, same as the function call without `new`.

So, both variables `no_new` and `with_new` will have a reference to a function in the following form:

```
function () {
    console.log('something');
    return new B();
}
```

(Note that `no_new` and `with_new` are equivalent but not identical. They do not refer to the same  object: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Krumia/bkm8jg6f/))

```js
function A() {
    return function(){
        console.log('something');
        return new B();
    }
}

function B() {
}

var no_new = A();
var with_new = new A();

alert(no_new);
alert(with_new);

var are_they_same = (no_new === with_new);
alert(are_they_same);
```